# Ubuntu don`t see my usb stick

Tags: usb

My pc don`t see my usb stick , 8Gb (7.41Gb). FAT32

Last time I use it was 4-5h ago , in w7.

I have 2 movies and some files on that stick , and I really don`t want to format it.

I`m new on Ubuntu :D  , but I like learn new things.

Links to img:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtCSF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWGgR.png

GParted is usless.

Comment: If you didn't eject the USB stick in Windows before rebooting, it may have gone to read-only mode, but shouldn't fail to detect at all.  Can you verify that Ubuntu is seeing the USB port(s)?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably formatted to `exfat`. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

and try again.